# Installing mahout on a cluster Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mahout, cloudera

I have configured a cluster hadoop using cloudera CDH 5.3.

I created a 4 nodes cluster and now want to install mahout on it.

I did add the `.jar` file of mahout in the cluster but i don't know what to do next.

Should I make the installation in the 4 nodes?

Comment: I think your question is better on Serverfault.

Comment: I've tried to make your sentence a bit more straightforward so your question can be read faster.